# Stymied by recent changes in browser javascript DOMParser and XSL

Tags: javascript, firefox, xslt, dom, cross-browser

The following used to work on Firefox 3.5.x and 3.6.x but it no longer does in Firefox 11.x or Safari 5.1.x. Javascript isn't my specialty, so I'm not up to speed on recent changes.

Specifically, the Browse button apparently still 'successfully' loads a file (which should be an XML sequence export from FCP although this is not validated), but upon pressing the Process button the results of the XSLT no longer appear in the 'output' DIV as they used to with previous browser versions.

It can be seen in context at http://johnpilgrim.net/color/jProcess.html

An appropriate sample XML file for testing is available at  http://johnpilgrim.net/color/sample.xml

Nothing changed in the html, javascript or xsl so it seems to be a change in the recent browsers. I only designed and tested it to work in Firefox, and so never tested it in anything else.

Thoughts? Solutions?

Thanks!
John

```
<head>

    <script type="text/javascript">

        function jProcess(){
            // Get the file contents locally, using the nifty Firefox 3 nsIDOMFile interface
            var file_contents = document.getElementById('xml_file').files.item(0).getAsText("utf8");

            // Cast/Convert to an XML Document
            var parser = new DOMParser();
            xmlDoc = parser.parseFromString(file_contents, "text/xml");

            // XSLT Transformation
            var xslt = document.implementation.createDocument("", "", null);
            xslt.async = false;
            xslt.load("jProcess.xsl");
            var process = new XSLTProcessor();
            process.importStylesheet(xslt);
            var result = process.transformToFragment(xmlDoc, document);

            // Show the output
            document.getElementById('output').innerHTML= " ";               
            document.getElementById('output').appendChild(result);

            return false;
        };
    </script>
</head>

<body>
<form method="post" onsubmit="return jProcess();">
<fieldset>
    <legend>Select the XML file for the FCP sequence you want to process into HTML.</legend>
    <input type="file" size=100 name="xml_file" id="xml_file">
    <input type="submit" value="Convert">
</fieldset>
</form>
<div id="output"></div>
```

Comment: +1 for good explanation, cool name "John Pilgrim" and use of word "stymied" in the OP.

Answer (score 3):

I tried your sample with Firefox 12 on Windows, the error console shows an error

```
Timestamp: 01.05.2012 11:23:43
Error: document.getElementById("xml_file").files.item(0).getAsText is not a function
Source File: http://johnpilgrim.net/color/jProcess.html
Line: 40
```

so the code simply does not work any more due to changes in the API exposed on the input type="file" control respectively the `File` objects exposed in the `FileList` exposed by that control. Based on https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/File the method getAsText was obsoleted in Gecko/FF 7 and probably removed later on. To read the contents of a file you are now supposed to use https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/FileReader#readAsText%28%29. That seems to be a further asynchronous API so you will have to restructure your code: http://home.arcor.de/martin.honnen/xml/test2012050101.html (that sample works for me with current version of Firefox, Opera and Chrome).

So an example using FileReader looks like

```
function transform(file, sheetUrl) {
  if (typeof FileReader !== 'undefined') {
    var fileReader = new FileReader();
    fileReader.onload = function(evt) {
      var doc = new DOMParser().parseFromString(this.result, 'application/xml');
      var proc = new XSLTProcessor();
      var req = new XMLHttpRequest();
      req.open('GET', sheetUrl, false);
      req.send(null);
      proc.importStylesheet(req.responseXML);
      document.body.appendChild(proc.transformToFragment(doc, document));
    };
    fileReader.readAsText(file);
  }
  else {
    console.log('No FileReader support.');
  }
}
```